# Android Playing sound in AsyncTask when ToggleButton is checked

Tags: android, loops, audio, android-asynctask, togglebutton

I am trying to set a sound that is going to be looped in intervals of 1 second when toggle button is checked. I tried to make asynctask for that but then when I open this activity it crashes why? What should I do to make it loop sound in 1 second intervals when toggle button is checked?

Solved by AlexanderFox

My current java code:

```
    final ToggleButton metronomepp = (ToggleButton) findViewById (R.id.metronomepp);
    metronomepp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("Metronome", "InWhile");

                if(isChecked) {
                    currentTask = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (metronome.isPlaying()) { metronome.pause(); }
                            metronome.seekTo(0);
                            metronome.start();
                        }
                    };
                    myTimer.schedule(currentTask, 0, 1000); 
                } else {
                    currentTask.cancel();
               }   
        }
    });
```

I am now having problem with changing time to wait. I have double variable timetw and chnaged 1000 to timetw with cast to long but app crashes when I check toggle button if I had changed time based on selection in app.

Comment: that's a null pointer exception. it means something is null. post the _full_ stack trace, and you'll magically see where it comes from, as if it were written in plain.

Comment: have you added the com.example.guitartools.MetronomeActivity Activity in your manifest file?

Comment: Where can I see full stack trace?

Comment: Activitz is aded to manifest and it works if I don't have async task but with it crashes.

Comment: From the logcat: `at com.example.guitartools.MetronomeActivity.<init>(MetronomeActivity.java:30)` - so what is happening on line 30 of `MetronomeActivity.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using infinite "while" loop is very bad idea. Better use [schedule](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) method of Timer class to reach that. When you no longer need this task to be repeated just call "cancel" method of Timer.

For example (corrected):

```
private TimerTask currentTask;

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        currentTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (metronome.isPlaying()) { metronome.pause(); }
                metronome.seekTo(0);
                metronome.start();
            }
        };
        myTimer.schedule(currentTask, 0, 1000); //in this line we tell to repeat sound every second without start delay
    } else {
        currentTask.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for first time when I check toggle button and uncheck it, but when I check it again app crashes.

Comment: May you provide full stacktrace of error? Or it equals to an error in description?

Comment: ok, that's my fault, corrected the answer: you can't add new tasks after you cancel timer, but you can cancel task itself.