# How To call activity on single button clicked?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I am calling activity from single button clicked. I am putting my code here. So problem is when I am calling my rules activity on rules button clicked it calls it, but it also calls on other option button too.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** the button that I've added in the xml*/
Button options_btn;
Button Exit_label;
Button player_data_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.cyk_main);

    /** Get the id of the button from the xml*/
    options_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.options_btn);
    options_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    /** Get the id of the button from the xml*/
    player_data_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.player_data_btn);
    player_data_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /** make a refernce to store the intent when the view has been clicked*/
    Intent intent;
    Intent intent1;
    /** Make cases according to the number of buttons you have in screen
     * In this case, I've added one.*/
    switch(view.getId()){

    case R.id.options_btn :
        Log.i("btnClick","Start button id is"+view.getId());
        /** Intent should be fired from this activity to the other activity*/
        intent = new Intent(Main.this, SoundLayout.class);
        /** This is useful when you want to get the button that is clicked here on the 
         * destination activity*/
        intent.putExtra("button_click", "Start");
        /** Start the intent*/
        startActivity(intent);

    case R.id.player_data_btn :
        Log.i("btnClick","Start button id is"+view.getId());
        /** Intent should be fired from this activity to the other activity*/
      intent1 = new Intent(Main.this, RulesActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("button_click", "Start");
        /** Start the intent*/
        startActivity(intent1);


        /*** Use this only when you want to finish your current activity while opening an another one.
         * if this is commented, then this activity will be running in the background.
        ***/
        this.finish();
        break;
    }


     Button Exit_label=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Exit_label);
     Exit_label.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
     //Set a title
     builder.setTitle("Exit?");
     //Set a message
     builder.setMessage("Want to Exit?");
     builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //Displaying a toast message
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Game Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     finish();
     System.exit(0);
     }
     });
     builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     dialog.cancel();

     }
     });

     //Create the dialog
     AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();
     //show the alertdialog
     alertdialog.show();
     }
     });

     }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}   
}
```

Here when I am calling my rules then it also come on the option button. So how can I solve this?

Comment: In first case: break statement is missing. That might surely be the cause of error.

Comment: Unrelated, but do not use System.exit() in Android...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need break after case statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710300/why-do-we-need-break-after-case-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must place a `break statement at the end of every case`. You are `missing the break statement`  in the end of first case. So if the first case if true, once the first case is executed, the second case will also be executed due to the absence of `break` statement at the end of first case. This is causing the problem.

```
switch(view.getId()){

case R.id.options_btn :
    ....
     break; // you are missing this
case R.id.player_data_btn :
    ....
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not mentioned the break statement for the first case statement.
add the break it will work..

Comment: yeah it work's can u help me on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144522/how-to-add-sound-on-the-toggle-button.

Comment: For that you have to create a media player object and and write a listener oncheckedchangelistener..

Comment: may be this will hepls you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427797/android-playing-sound-in-asynctask-when-togglebutton-is-checked

Comment: this link doen't help me..:(